# Virtual Wireless Setup

Tags: debian, wireless-access-point

I'm running two Debian machines and I would like to set up a network between the two.  I want one machine to act like an AP running HostAPD and the second to connect to it.  The problem is, where I'm at I can't just broadcast wireless.  I was hoping to find a way to emulate a virtual connection between the two computers so that I could continue to configure the two devices and setup the network without ever having to actually broadcast an SSID (not even a hidden SSID) from the AP.  I figured maybe there was some kind of physical connection that could, with help from some software, trick both devices into thinking that the connection is wireless.

Is this possible?  I've looked around, but I haven't been able to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends exactly on what you mean.

If your question is about making your system invisible to a dogged pursuer with a good sniffer, then no, it cannot be done. We are dealing with electromagnetic radiation which freely moves about in a transparent medium like air, and our sources are, for obvious reasons, non-directional. Thus some fraction of energy will fall upon the dogged pursuer's antenna, and your presence will be revealed.

You can, however, make the pursuer's life more difficult trough two tricks (perhaps there are more?). The first one is to suppress SSID broadcast, which is more effective than you seem to believe. The command to be inserted into hostapd.conf is

```
  ignore_broadcast_ssid=1
```

This has two effects: it both sends an empty (=0 length) SSID in its beacon, and ignores probe requests. This means it is basically sitting idly waiting for someone knowledgeable to call.

The other trick lies of course in lowering the transmission power of both of your pcs. If they are rather close and do not need much power, you may then reduce it so as to make your system nearly invisible just a short distance away. The relevant command is

```
  iwconfig wlan0 txpower 70
```

50 is just my value, you will have to experiment with this. Remember to do this on both pcs,
and that this will degrade your connection speed.

Comment: My goal was to not transmit anything at all.  To emulate a wireless connection over a wired connection.